A special property of a system of linear equations in n > 3 dimensions
The origin of the question is physics, so I have to explain the idea behind it.
In three dimensions the Lorentz force $F$ of a magnetic field $B$ on a particle (with charge $q = 1$) with velocity $v$ is given by
$$ F = v \times B $$
Determining $B$ from measurements means: i) prepare a velocity vector $v$, ii) measure the force $F$, iii) solve for $B$. With one measurement we cannot determine the component of $B$ parallel to $v$, so we need two measurements using two non-parallel vectors $v^{(1)}$ and $v^{(2)}$ (proof is straightforward).
I want to generalize this to $D \ge 3$ dimensions.
In an arbitrary frame, using an anti-symmetric 2nd rank tensor i.e. a matrix for $B$, the Lorentz force reads
$$ F_i = \sum_k B_{ik} \, v_k $$
with $ i,k=1 \ldots D$.
One solution with $D-1$ measurements is: for the $(n)$-th measurement chose the $n$-th direction for the velocity, i.e.
$$ (v_i)^{(n)} = |v| \, \delta_{in} $$
$$ F_i^{(n)} = |v| \, B_{in} $$
$$ B_{in} = -B_{ni}  = |v|^{-1} \, F_i^{(n)} $$
The question is whether it can be done better, i.e. whether it is possible to reduce the number of measurements.
In $D = 3$ it's obvious that it's not possible, so one needs $2 = D-1$ measurements.
Going through that stuff for $D = 4$ one finds that with an ansatz
$$ (v_i)^{(1)} = |v| \, \delta_{i1} = (|v|, 0, 0, 0)$$
$$ (v_i)^{(2)} = (0, v_2, v_3, v_4) $$
there are never enough independent equations in step $(2)$, so again one needs $3 = D-1$ measurements.
This led me to the conjecture that in any number of dimensions $D \ge 3$ we need $D-1$ measurements, i.e. that I already found one optimal solution. My question is how to prove or disprove this conjecture for arbitrary.
There is one observation that might help. $B$ is anti-symmetric which means it has $ D(D-1)/2 $ independent components and can be written as
$$ B_{ik} = \sum_{A=(mn)} (t_A)_{ik} \, b_A  $$
The double-index $A = (mn)$ runs over all pairs $m \neq n$; $b_A$ are the independent components of $B$. The matrices $t_A$ are related to the generators of $SO(D)$ and can be written as
$$ (t_{(mn)})_{ik} = \delta_{im}\delta_{kn} - \delta_{in}\delta_{km} $$
i.e. each matrix for $A = (mn)$ has two non-zero entries $+1$ at $(ik) = (mn)$ and $-1$ at $(ik) = (nm)$.
The above mentioned equations can be rewritten as
$$ F_i^{(n)} = B_{ik} (v_k)^{(n)} = \sum_{A} (t_A)_{ik} \, b_A (v_k)^{(n)} = \sum_A \left( \sum_k  (t_A)_{ik} (v_k)^{(n)} \right) b_A = \sum_A V_{i, A}^{(n)} \, b_A  $$
$$ V_{i, A}^{(n)} = \sum_k  (t_A)_{ik} (v_k)^{(n)} $$
$$ F_i^{(n)} = \sum_A V_{i, A}^{(n)} \, b_A  $$
Introducing a second double-index $B = ((n), i)$ we get
$$ F_B = \sum_A V_{BA} \, b_A  $$
with
$$ A = 1 \ldots D(D-1)/2 $$
$$ B = 1 \ldots ND$$
$$n = 1 \ldots N$$
and all $v_i^{(n)}$ to be determined such that the number of measurements $N$ is minimized.
Now let me rephrase my question for the reformulated equation $ F_B = \sum_A V_{BA} \, b_A $: what is the minimum number of measurements $N$ such that this equation can be solved uniquely? (and what would be the appropriate velocities?)
(I know that this may be related to generalized inverse or left-inverse of a matrix)
